# Access existing collections using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've just started working with Mongoose and I have a question related to accessing existing collections.
Let's say I have two separate files, once in which I'm filling the database. I define my collections there, create models and save some data.

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var mySchema = new Schema({
  project:  String,
  data: Object
});

myModel = mongoose.model('myModel', mySchema);
```

In second file, I would like to get those collections and to query them, but I'm not sure how to do it. Not sure how to instantiate those collections created in another file. 
When I try simply:

```
var model = mongoose.model('myModel');
```

I got `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "myModel".`

I saw that I can get names of collections, but not sure what to do with that and how to use it.

```
mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function (err, names) {
    console.log(names);
    module.exports.Collection = names;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the models available to both files by putting the schema and model definitions in a separate file that both of your main files use [`require`](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_require) to load as a module.

Comment: Thanks, JohnnyHK, this helped me. I'm still new with nodejs and mongo, so I didn't realize some of the concepts.